# Como criar um menu de múltiplos níveis com AdminLTE Menu Runtime no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, adminlte

Integrei o [jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#menu-configuration-at-runtime) a um projeto **Laravel 5.7**, entretanto, estou com dificuldade para gerar um menu com múltiplos níveis.

Segundo a referência contida no repositório do projeto [jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE#menu-configuration-at-runtime), este seria o código para gerar um menu em tempo de execução;

```
public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
{
    $events->listen(BuildingMenu::class, function (BuildingMenu $event) {
        $event->menu->add(trans('menu.pages'));

        $items = Page::all()->map(function (Page $page) {
            return [
                'text' => $page['title'],
                'url' => route('admin.pages.edit', $page)
            ];
        });

        $event->menu->add(...$items);
    });
}
```

O modelo acima estava retornando erro, então tive que fazer algumas alterações:

```
public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
{
    $events->listen(BuildingMenu::class, function (BuildingMenu $event) {
        $event->menu->add(trans('menu.pages'));

        $items = Page::all()->map(function (Page $page) use ($event){
            $event->menu->add([
                'text' => $page['name'],
                'url' => $page['url']
            ]);;
        });


    });
}
```

Agora está funcionando, porém, ainda não consegui resolver a questão do menu com múltiplos níveis. Um outro fator de problema é que a quantidade de níveis é indefinida. Como posso criar múltiplos níveis considerando a abordagem do projeto supracitado? Considerando que em meu banco tenho basicamente as colunas: id, title, url e parent_id.